# Bag of Visual Words: is feature extraction even needed?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering, bag-of-words

I'm currently implementing a BoVW as part of my lab project. The steps the algorithm used are as follows:

1. spliting all photos into patches
2. cluster these pathces using K-means based on pixel values of each patch
3. describe each photo as an histogram of how much of each cluster its patches belongs to
4. use SVM to classify the data

now, my PI wants me to implements one more step: feature extraction. He suggested PCA, tSNE, auto-encoder and so on.In a lot of implementions I checked out for BoVW there is such a thing, usually auto-encoder, so it's a reasonable request.

The thing is: why is this step even needed? **Isnt just by describing each photo as an histogram we applied feature extraction of some sort** ? Why is adding this step we add no value, but just overcomplicate things?

Thank you all for any insights to this.